# Firebase Task finished with error - code: -1200

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I am unable to access data from Firebase storage on my iOS app on my current connection. When I connect to a VPN, it allows me to connect and download data from Firebase Storage normally. I have also tried to allow arbitrary loads but to no use. Any suggestions?

**The following is the code:**

```
let tempImageRef = storage.child("CoverArt/Issue15.jpg") 

tempImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1*1000*1000) { (data, error) in 
if (error == nil) 
{ //Do something } 

else { print(error!.localizedDescription) } }
```

**The following is the error:**

```
Task <D343DC6F-2D37-4246-A0BA-4044BF36C83D>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200 An unknown error occurred, please check the server response. 

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

Comment: Firebase has a well rounded error handling system where most functions have a closure that can return an error. From that error you can determine what the issue is. Can you please include the code that generates the error and perhaps add proper error handling or error printing to the actual line of code that's failing? You may also have a Firewall of other security issue but again, without that code and knowing what line is failing, it's hard to say.

Comment: I have had problems relating to this `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection` errors, starting today. Check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912404/ssl-error-ssl1-operation-failed-within-the-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL\_ERROR\_SSL(1): operation failed within the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912404/ssl-error-ssl1-operation-failed-within-the-library)